# How does an EventAggregator register events and subscribers and notify all subscribers of events firing?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, eventaggregator

I read up on the EventAggregator pattern, specifically for MVVM and while I get the idea that one class registers an event within it and other classes can subscribe to that event and I've seen some interfaces I fail to imagine how the code would actually work.

How can you register an event and subscribe to it?

Furthermore how would subscribers be notified of an event's firing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the event aggregator.

In Prism's version, you publish a `MessageSentEvent` (`public class MessageSentEvent : PubSubEvent<string> {}` ) like this:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<MessageSentEvent>().Publish("hello");
```

...and subscribe to it like this:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<MessageSentEvent>().Subscribe(message => MessageBox.Show(message));
```

There is a full code example available on [GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/14-UsingEventAggregator).

The [view model in ModuleA](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/14-UsingEventAggregator/ModuleA/ViewModels/MessageViewModel.cs) sends a message to the [view model in ModuleB](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/14-UsingEventAggregator/ModuleB/ViewModels/MessageListViewModel.cs).

Comment: Thanks, but it's the exact functioning of the "Publish" and "Subscribe" methods I'm interested in. In other words "how does an event aggregator register events and notify all subscribers of their firing?". Which, now that I think about it, is a better question title. Let me edit it.

Comment: Why don't you look in the repo I linked to? You'll find the implementation there: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/2ecbf13ed59b288d8d88446b535780bdc211b6e1/Source/Prism/Events/EventAggregator.cs

Comment: I did, but the EventAggregator example project uses Prism library methods, which are obfuscated (I guess) or whatever and their source code isn't available. Wait, my mistake, I'm looking at the link in your comment...

Comment: @J.Doe: Obfuscated? Certainly not. Prism is open-sourced.

Comment: I thought they are because "Going to definition" just yields metadata, instead of actual code?

Comment: That's because you haven't downloaded the source code. But what has this do with your question? What's your current issue and why haven't you even bothered to upvote the answer yet...?

Comment: Nothing, it was just something I didn't know and was pondering about. Sorry, I haven't upvoted and accepted your answer, yet I was being sidetracked by urgent issues and still haven't finished looking through the code. I'll do it now. :)